# Remove unwanted characters from sharepoint user displayname in infopath

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am populating infopath repeating table with sharepoint list item. In the list one of the column is "Approver"(PersonOrGroup) type. While I am displaying this column(Display Name) in infopath repeating table, I am getting the below value:

```
LastName,, FirstName,#,#,#
```

I want to remove unwanted characters from the display name and want to display in below format:

```
LastName, FirstName ;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
concat(substring-before(field1, ","), ",", " ", substring-before(substring(field1, string-length(substring-before(field1, ",")) + 3), ","), " ", ";")
```

The +3 there is the count of two commas(,) and 1 space.

example is:

Doe,, John,#,#,#

RESULT:

Doe, John ;